# Postman - pass array in GET URL

Tags: arrays, syntax, get, postman

In my project I need to test a GET request with Postman with an array of IDs in the URL:

`{{ws}}{{url}}/v1/devices/["{{test_devices}}"]/preview/`

In the pre-request script I set the value of test_devices:

```
pm.environment.set("test_devices",['4d9a0f69-1de2-40e3-a907-03de4fedf0ec', '392bf056-99d8-4a2f-ba1a-246c1f01394c']);
```

But I the syntax seems to be off as  I get this error:

```
ValidationError at /v1/devices/["4d9a0f69-1de2-40e3-a907-03de4fedf0ec,392bf056-99d8-4a2f-ba1a-246c1f01394c"]/preview/
['\'["4d9a0f69-1de2-40e3-a907-03de4fedf0ec,392bf056-99d8-4a2f-ba1a-246c1f01394c"]\' is not a valid UUID.']
```

I've tried several variations, but all with similar issues. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stringify and set the array.

1. Update your request URL like so:

`{{ws}}{{url}}/v1/devices/{{test_devices}}/preview/`

2. Update your test script to do a JSON.stringify on the array, like so:

```
pm.environment.set("test_devices",JSON.stringify(['4d9a0f69-1de2-40e3-a907-03de4fedf0ec', '392bf056-99d8-4a2f-ba1a-246c1f01394c']));
```